# Declare method outside of class

Tags: javascript, methods

i know i can add a method by doing:

```
point.prototype.move = function () 
{
     this.x += 1;
}
```

But, **is there a way to add a method to a class by assigning a function that is declared outside of it to one of its propertie?**
I am pretty sure this can't work but it gives an idea about what i'am trying to do:

```
function point(x, y)
{
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
     this.move = move();
}

function move()
{
     this.x += 1;
}
```

Comment: Well, did you test it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only reason your example doesn't work is because you are calling `move()` and assigning its result which is undefined.

You should just use a reference to the `move` function when assigning it.

```
function move()
{
     this.x += 1;
}

function point(x, y)
{
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
     this.move = move
}
```

**Different ways to do it**

```
// Attach the method to the prototype
// point.prototype.move = move;

// Attach the method to the instance itself
// var myPoint = new point(1,2); myPoint.move = move;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function point(x, y, move)
{
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
     this.move = move;
}

function move()
{
     this.x += 1;
}

var obj =  new point(2, 5, move);
```